# Filling an array with objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor

Currently I have an issue with filling an array which I call `input` in my code with the object which I call `athlete` in my code.The object which is called `athlete` is instantiated using several other arrays. I have attached a jsfiddle link to this post which is basically a simplified version with the same issue. I know the logic might look redundant but that is because it is necessary for this example(the actual logic will work with user input).

My issue is that I am filling an array with `new Athlete` objects, yet I cannot access a specific property of an object in the array.

I am new to working with objects so I'd appreciate any advice on how to make this work. I have added a last line of code to display my input array.

```
var input = new Array();
var girl=[1,1,1,1];
var boy = [1,1,1,1];
var balleyscore = [100,400,320,50];
var boyHeight = [72,68,65,75];
var girlHeight=[60,57,65,55];
var boyAge = [19,32,22,25];
var girlAge = [20,15,32,18];
//the above are all generate from user inputs
// they go into the object constructor below
function athlete(girl, boy,balleyscore, height, age){
this.girl=girl;
this.boy=boy;
this.balleyscore=balleyscore;
this.height=height;
this.age = age;
};
function insertToObjectArray()
{  
  var j=0;                
  var i=0;  //insert all our data into one array of the load object
    for(j = 0; j < girl.length;j++)
    {
      input[j]= new athlete(true,false,balleyscore[j],girlHeight[j],girlAge[j]);
    }
    for(j = girl.length; j <=girl.length+boy.length;j++)
    {
      input[j]= new athlete(false,true,0,boyHeight[i],boyAge[i]);
      i++;
    }
};
insertToObjectArray();

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=input;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qC5j4/1/

Comment: `I cannot access a specific property of an object in the array.` is not enough to debug the program. :(

Comment: And which property are you trying to access? What exactly does not work as you expect it?

Comment: I need to be able to access every property

Comment: What does not work is that my data is not being stored properly into the properties of the athlete object. If you output input[1].age for example it is undefined

Comment: what properties has your object [athlete]?

Comment: still not sure what your problem is, replace height with age in my update of your fiddle below and the age is correctly there.

Comment: can you give an example of when this goes wrong for you?

Comment: Hi everyone I really just need to be able to access the properties of my objects later for calculators. I need to be able to do something like input[1].age * input[1].height but this is not possible because I cannot access these properties without putting them in another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a property of an object in your array input:

```
input[0].age
```

this will allow you to access the first athlete's age

can also be accessed like so:

```
input[0]['age']
```

Either way they will both display 20 as the age of the first athlete in the array.

Check it out by console.log(input) in the debugger and then you can play with the data structure.

Ex:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=input[0].age;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure of your problem, here I have updated your fiddle to display the height property of your athletes by adding the line

```
output[j]= input[j].height
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoyTheB0y/qC5j4/4/)

Comment: Why can't I just display the height using input[j].height?

Comment: I need to be able to access these properties for calculations later, putting the properties back into another array is defeating the purpose of creating an object.

Comment: you can do this, in your fiddle you have an array of objects which you wrote to the screen , so you got 'Object' displayed, I just changed to output to the screen to be Object.property so that the property was displayed

Answer (score 1):

You can access your objects by array index and property name. Change this line `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=input` to this code (list all objects sex and balleyscore in ul#demo):

```
for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    var node = document.createElement('li'),
        txt = document.createTextNode(
            (input[i].girl? 'girl' : 'boy') + ' ' + input[i].balleyscore);
    node.appendChild(txt);
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node);
}
```

html:

```
<p><ul id="demo"></ul></p>
```

[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/qC5j4/7/)

Browser console is very useful for debugging purposes. Try to add this line after objects creation and inspect your array in console:

```
insertToObjectArray();
console.log(input);     // output input array to console
```

Answer (score 1):

Your athlete object should be for example:

```
function athlete(age)
{
  this.age = age;
}

var item = new athlete(10);
item.age;//10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show the height and age like this:

```
var output = "";
for(var i = 0, length = input.length; i !== length; i++) {
    output += "height: "+input[i].height + ", age: " + input[i].age + "<br />";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=output;
```

And there is a little mistake. Use

```
j < girl.length+boy.length
```

instead of

```
j <=girl.length+boy.length
```

Comment: anyway, that's a dangerous construct. rather use for(i=0; i < boy.length; i++, j++) {...}, where i is the index for boys, and j is the index in input.